# How to filter a dataset according to datetime values in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am trying to filter my data according to it's datetime field. A sample from my data:

```
303,0.00001747,4351040,75.9054,"2019-03-08 19:29:18"
```

This is how I initialize spark:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app name").setMaster("spark://192.168.1.124:7077");
    JavaSparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf));
```

Firstly, I read the data above into my custom object like below:

```
    // Read data from file into custom object
    JavaRDD<CurrencyPair> rdd = sc.textFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/data.csv", 2).map(
        new Function<String, CurrencyPair>() {
            public CurrencyPair call(String line) throws Exception {
                String[] fields = line.split(","); // Split line from commas

                // read each data into custom object
                CurrencyPair cp = new CurrencyPair();
                cp.setId(Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim()));
                cp.setValue(Double.parseDouble(fields[1].trim()));
                cp.setBaseVolume(Double.parseDouble(fields[2].trim()));
                cp.setQuoteVolume(Double.parseDouble(fields[3].trim()));
                cp.setTimeStamp(new Date(fields[4].trim()));

                System.out.println("Date:" + fields[4].trim()); // To see if it will print or not

                return cp;
            }
        }
     );
```

In order to get the data which has timestamp bigger than a certain time, I wrote this filter:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10); // This is for test issue

    // My filter to get the data for a certain time range
    Function<CurrencyPair, Boolean> filter = new Function<CurrencyPair, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(CurrencyPair currencyPair) throws Exception {
            if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(currencyPair.getTimeStamp()) > 0){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

This is how my custom object looks like:

```
public class CurrencyPair implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private double value;
    private double baseVolume;
    private double quoteVolume;
    private Date timeStamp;

    // all getters and setters are here, but no constructor
}
```

To check the results of my filter, I tried to see some of them(first 100 here):

```
Iterator<CurrencyPair> result = rdd.repartition(100).filter(filter).toLocalIterator();
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 100 && result.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Here: " + result.next());
    counter++;
}
```

But the problem is that when I run my code I got the following exception at the line where I write the first 100 result (Here: System.out.println("Here: " + result.next());)

Error:

```
19/05/12 00:05:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on 192.168.1.124, executor 0: java.lang.ClassCastException (cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

In my filter, I also write the datetime string to console with using System.out.println, but I can not see the result of it in the console as well. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

---

**Edit:** I noticed that I actually downloaded spark 2.3.0 version but in my maven file I was using 2.4.2. So I changed my maven file to 2.3.0 version.

This time I am getting the following error:

```
19/05/14 00:35:35 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/05/14 00:35:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/05/14 00:35:35 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/05/14 00:35:36 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
at spark.BasicSpark.readDataFile(BasicSpark.java:107)
at spark.BasicSpark.getWholeData(BasicSpark.java:39)
at controller.TableScreenController$2.handle(TableScreenController.java:66)
at controller.TableScreenController$2.handle(TableScreenController.java:62)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$208(GtkApplication.java:245)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/05/14 00:35:36 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
19/05/14 00:35:36 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
at spark.BasicSpark.readDataFile(BasicSpark.java:107)
at spark.BasicSpark.getWholeData(BasicSpark.java:39)
at controller.TableScreenController$2.handle(TableScreenController.java:66)
at controller.TableScreenController$2.handle(TableScreenController.java:62)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$208(GtkApplication.java:245)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am getting this error at the below code line where I initialize spark context:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf));
```

---

Edit 2: It works well when I write local instead of my own spark master IP. But I need to run this on my own IP. So what can be wrong with my master node?

---

Edit 3: I uploaded whole error stack to code snippet that located under the first edit.

Comment: the problem probably not in the print, spark actions are lazy evaluated, means they aren't executed until data is requested (and therefore only then you get runtime exception). can you post the full code where you use the filter?

Comment: @matanper I have already post that part in here "textFile.repartition(100).filter(filter).toLocalIterator();". I did not write any piece of code other than these.

Comment: @matanper Thank you for your comment by the way. I noticed that I forgot the part where I initialize the spark, so I edited the question. The version in my maven file was wrong, so I changed it but this time another error came up. I added it all into the question.

Comment: It's looks like spark isn't running or the URL is wrong, try using telnet to see spark is listening on this address

Comment: @matanper When I look at to the localhost:8080 which the management GUI of the spark is located, I can see this: Spark Master at spark://192.168.1.124:7077. Also the status of it is "ALIVE".

Comment: Try `telnet 192.168.1.124 7077`

Comment: @matanper When I tried `telnet 192.168.1.124 7077`, I got `Trying 192.168.1.124...
Connected to 192.168.1.124.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @matanper I added full error stacktrace for both of them.

Comment: Does the spark context getting initialised.? Are you getting "ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext." somewhere in your console logs. Please share the console log when you are try to run the application. Also you can enable the debug logging to get more details.

Comment: @AmitKumar Thank you for your comment. Yes I am getting `ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.` error. I shared the whole stacktrace under the area of first edit header. What should I do? I can see my workers and master that they are alive actually at spark GUI master:7077.

Comment: @AmitKumar @matanper I had solved the issues above and now I am getting this for my iterator objects: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
`. In order to iterate a javardd I used java.util. But it seems it does not accept it and when I use scala.collection.Iterator, the IDEA gives a type not matched error. How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This happens when class that defines lambda expression is not available run time. If you are trying to run job on remote cluster from local IDE, you will need to add setJars

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("app name")
                .setJars(new String[]{"/fatJarPath/jar.path"})
                .setMaster("spark://Remote_spark_ip:port");
```

Alternatively you can build fat jar and submit your job using spark-submit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I tried what you said before. But this time I got file not found error for the nodes other than my master node which I run my IDE on it. So I added the jar file to the same dir with master node to all slaves. Then I got rid of this error, but this time it started to give this error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
`.

Comment: I got the error above when I tried to collect data from rdd `rdd.collect()`(It is for the second code snippet that I shared above). The problem may be the way I build jar file. I just used IntelliJ's build artifact feature, maybe I need to do that with maven. Do you have any about this?

Comment: This so answer should help you for building fat jar(uber jar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415182/packaging-and-running-scala-spark-project-with-maven

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately I got the same error that I mentioned above.