# Filtering Custom Data Structure In Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd, distributed-computing

I am trying to read a csv file into JavaRDD. In order to do that, I wrote the code below:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NameOfApp").setMaster("spark://Ip here:7077");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<CurrencyPair> rdd_records = sc.textFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/data.csv", 2).map(
        new Function<String, CurrencyPair>() {
            public CurrencyPair call(String line) throws Exception {
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                CurrencyPair sd = new CurrencyPair(Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim()), Double.parseDouble(fields[1].trim()),
                        Double.parseDouble(fields[2].trim()), Double.parseDouble(fields[3]), new Date(fields[4]));
                return sd;
            }
        }
);
```

My data file looks like this:

```
1,0.034968,212285,7457.23,"2019-03-08 18:36:18"
```

Here, in order to check that if my data loaded correctly or not, I tried to print some of them:

```
System.out.println("Count: " + rdd_records.count());
List<CurrencyPair> list = rdd_records.top(5);
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

But I had following error at both system out lines. I tried each of them alone as well rather than printing count and list at the same time.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

My custom object looks like this:

```
public class CurrencyPair implements Serializable {

private int id;
private double value;
private double baseVolume;
private double quoteVolume;
private Date timeStamp;

public CurrencyPair(int id, double value, double baseVolume, double quoteVolume, Date timeStamp) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.baseVolume = baseVolume;
    this.quoteVolume = quoteVolume;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public double getBaseVolume() {
    return baseVolume;
}

public void setBaseVolume(double baseVolume) {
    this.baseVolume = baseVolume;
}

public double getQuoteVolume() {
    return quoteVolume;
}

public void setQuoteVolume(double quoteVolume) {
    this.quoteVolume = quoteVolume;
}

public Date getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(Date timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}
}
```

So I could not figured out what is wrong here. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: It works well when I write local instead of my own spark master IP. But I need to run this on my own IP. So what can be wrong with my master node?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably the anonymous class definition `new Function<String, CurrencyPair>() {` which forces Spark to try to serialize the parent class as well. Try a lambda instead:

```
rdd_records.map(
  (Function<String, CurrencyPair>) line -> {
    ...
```

Note: You could read the file as a CSV instead and use the dataset API with a bean encoder to skip the manual parsing completely.

Comment: I tried lamda now, but I got the same error. Here is how I tried: https://i.hizliresim.com/QL6O5G.png

Comment: I have also shared same issue with bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048397/how-to-filter-a-dataset-according-to-datetime-values-in-spark

Comment: And `CurrencyPair` is not an inner class? The code worked for me after switching to lambda

Comment: No CurrencyPair is not an inner class? Should it be an inner class?

Comment: I made it inner class but I got the same error again. But I noticed that my spark version is 2.3.0 while the spark version in my pom.xml was 2.4.2. So I changed it to 2.3.0 and this time I got this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem` in this line: `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);`

Comment: I mean `CurrencyPair` should *not* be an inner class unless it's static or it will serialize the outer class as well. But as mentioned, the code itself seem to work with a lambda so must be something with the configuration or structure.

Comment: I understand, do you have any idea about what can be wrong here?

Comment: It is actually works well when I write local instead of my own IP. So do you have any suggestion about this?